# How to create a Mac OS .app bundle with Chef Omnibus in DMG installer

Tags: macos, chef-infra, installation, bundle, dmg

I have very limited knowledge of Mac OS and have a couple of questions related to DMG installers.

We have an application that runs on Windows, Mac and Ubuntu. We generate our installers for all three OSs with [Chef Omnibus](https://github.com/chef/omnibus).

Our DMG installer is a bit basic but works fine, i.e. our application is installed as it should. However, there's no easy way for our users to start the application - they need to go and look for the installation folder and locate the startup .sh file themselves and run it.

From what I've gathered so far a Mac OS bundle .app could help us a great deal with that. However, I don't find any information on how to create a bundle during the Omnibus installer creation process. I can see that a bundle is a collection of folders and files that [follow a specific structure](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW13):

- an info.plist file
- an executable - this could be our bash file mentioned above
- a Resources folder
- ...and various other files

I've found that the easiest way to create a bundle is using the xCode editor but it's not an option for us. We're creating the installers in a CI process automatically and we prefer to keep it that way, it's very efficient and reliable. The best would be to extend the Omnibus process somehow so that we also get this bundle file. However, at this point I'm not even sure if it's possible.

I'm really stuck so I'm grateful for any pointers.

Here's our distribution.xml file for reference in case it is relevant for this issue. It is used by Omnibus for the productbuild command. I've been looking into options to extend this but there's nothing related to bundles:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<installer-gui-script minSpecVersion="1">
 <title><%= friendly_name %></title>
 <background file="background.png" alignment="bottomleft" mime- 
   type="image/png"/>
 <welcome file="welcome.html" mime-type="text/html"/>
 <license file="license.html" mime-type="text/html"/>

 <!-- Generated by productbuild - - synthesize -->
 <pkg-ref id="<%= identifier %>"/>
 <options customize="never" require-scripts="false"/>
 <choices-outline>
  <line choice="default">
   <line choice="<%= identifier %>"/>
  </line>
 </choices-outline>
 <choice id="default"/>
 <choice id="<%= identifier %>" visible="false">
  <pkg-ref id="<%= identifier %>"/>
 </choice>
 <pkg-ref id="<%= identifier %>" version="<%= version %>" 
    onConclusion="none"><%= component_pkg %></pkg-ref>
 <domains enable_anywhere="false" enable_currentUserHome="true" 
   enable_localSystem="false" />
</installer-gui-script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> our application is installed as it should

It does sound like you need to generate an `.app` for your distribution.

The `.app` is a special folder structure:

```
MyApp.app/
   Contents/
      Info.plist
      MacOS/
          executable
      Frameworks/
          library.dylib
      Resources/
          icon.icns
```

Libraries in `Frameworks/` should be linked to the `executable` with `install_name_tool`

For example,

```
install_name_tool -change /opt/local/lib/library.dylib @rpath/library.dylib MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/executable
install_name_tool -add_rpath @executable_path/../Frameworks MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/executable
```

Most anything else can be categorized Resources, nothing can go into the top level of the app except the `Contents/` folder.
You may `codesign` when the app is finalized and fully bundled.

When you get back to your other software, use the `.app` to create a `.dmg`, then you may `codesign` that.

In typical installation with `.dmg`, the user is usually presented with the app and an alias to the /Applications folder.  To install, the user drags the app to the /Applications folder.

Some `.dmg` creation software will do more sophisticated things like display a background or an require an end-user license agreement.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll try what you've suggested.